# Does it make sense to provide a DQN with negative rewards for a network with relu and sigmoid activations?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn, rewards, relu, sigmoid

The creation of negative rewards leads to the chance of Q-values being negative. However, networks with relu or sigmoid activations, just cannot predict negative values. This will lead to a case where erroneous Q-values are being predicted. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A network with ReLU activation can predict negative values; we put ReLU between the hidden layers but return the output of the final layer without any activation function, or with a linear activation function to scale the output.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that some kind of non-linear activation function is *necessary* for hidden layers to be useful. Only in the output layer should be made linear in most cases (I hesitate to say *all* because although I cannot think of any reason, someone will probably know of a case where it is useful to have a linear hidden layer).